# Shared packages folder nuget, nuget.config ignored

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I have a shared repository for all of my solutions. My structure is as follows:

- repostiory/
- repository/project1/solution1
- repository/project2/solution2

I want nuget to download all packages to:

- repository/packages

I have added a nuget.config to the repository root with content as follows:

```
<configuration>
  <config>
    <add key="repositoryPath" value="packages" />
  </config>
</configuration>
```

According to what I have read this should be enough in order to have a shared packages folder? Instead, nuget seems to completely ignore the nuget.config files and instead put packages folder in each solution directory...

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a wild guess, but you could try the following:

You say you have a solution structure like this:

```
> repostiory\
> repostiory\NuGet.Config
> repository\solution1\project1
> repository\solution2\project2
```

(I switched solution and project, since that's the ways a Visual Studio solution is organized.)

Could it be that the `repositoryPath` specified inside the config file is *relative* to where the NuGet command is being run (by Visual Studio)? Which I assume will be inside the solution folder? If that is the case, then what you see is correct (since the packages folder will be inside each solution, as it normally is).

What if you instead specify either a relative path (e.g. `..\NuGet.Config`), or an absolute path in the config file?

Answer (score 0):

As Nailuj hinted, it's actually a bug in the implementation. NuGet doesn't currently support relative paths for that value. Which is a bummer.

https://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/2753

So, if you're feeling brave, you can roll up your sleeves and fix it :)

Comment: Looks like this has been fixed now. See http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/2810 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/nuget-config-file